# <code> doesn't ignore all code

Tags: html, code-snippets

I want to insert code snippets in my html document, but

```
<code></code>
```

tags don't seem to fix non-html code. I'm trying to insert this snippet for example:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent”
            android:orientation:”vertical”
                    tools:context=".LinearLayout" >
 </LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't show the snippet at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<code>` tags don't affect how nested HTML is parsed, and they don't encode HTML entities. That's up to you. If you want to display literal `<html>` tags, regardless of whether they're in a `<code>` tag or not, you need to use `&lt;html&gt;`. Otherwise, their parsed as HTML tags.

For example this snippet...

```
<code><h1>heading</h1></code>
```

Generates this output:

`heading`

To actually output the literal string `<h1>heading</h1>`, you need:

```
<code>&lt;h1&gt;heading&lt;/h1&gt;</code>
```

which outputs:

`<h1>heading</h1>`

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks. I'll then use a script that replaces all those symbols for me.